# How much overhead does RUST_BACKTRACE=1 have?

Tags: debugging, rust

Is it reasonable to just set RUST_BACKTRACE=1 always?

Does it introduce any (significant?) overhead during normal execution (such as during function calls) or is there only overhead when a panic happens?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only place in the standard library that reads the `RUST_BACKTRACE` environment variable is in the function [`sys_common::backtrace::log_enabled()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5c71e4ef90ef79c1ac79c4132333cbc80f5b85b9/src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs#L150). That function is only called from [`panicking::default_hook`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5c71e4ef90ef79c1ac79c4132333cbc80f5b85b9/src/libstd/panicking.rs#L337), which gets called after a panic occurs. Therefore, setting it should have no effect on performance unless a thread panics.

Note that this flag also affects the compiler itself (`rustc`). The compiler sometimes issues panics to cause a "normal" exit, suppressing printing the backtrace but still calculating it. This can happen when it exits after a compilation error. In the past, people have reported that this caused some versions of the compiler to take a long time to exit with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` set.

Some crates may also handle `RUST_BACKTRACE` themselves: For example, the `error_chain` crate generates a backtrace when an error is generated and `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` is set. This can slow down projects using this crate. A notable project which uses `error_chain` is `cargo`.

Comment: *Therefore, setting it should have no effect on performance unless a thread panics* — Any ideas why this statement disagrees [with my experimental results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45400966/155423)?

Comment: @Shepmaster There are too many variables in your testing: you are measuring the time for browser+webserver+cargo+compilation+running. All of this is presumably running in a sandbox which could slow things down. Did you try testing just running the executable?

Comment: You are correct that my testing includes the browser+webserver, but those are constants across the runs and are against my local machine with nothing else happening . Running inside the Docker container is also a constant. Note I'm not trying to say that the whole process is *slow* or *fast*, just that using `RUST_BACKTRACE` is slower than not — the baseline. The program is compiled from scratch in the exact same configuration (yay Docker) and the only thing I vary is when the `RUST_BACKTRACE` variable is set — the 3 cases in my tables. The variance of the data is also very low.

Answer (score 10):

I asked about this in `#rust-internals`, and `sfackler` said

> I believe it has no effect except during a panic

Comment: So why isn't it on for all debug builds all the time then?

Comment: It's an environment variable. So the setting comes from outside, not inside.

Comment: I get that it is an environment variable.  I was asking, why not just make the behavior of any rust exe compiled in debug mode that it always has the behavior of `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` regardless of the environment variable.

Comment: I don't know, it's been like this for at least 3 years.

Answer (score 9):

This is of interest to me as the Rust Playground would [like to have `RUST_BACKTRACE` enabled all the time](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/issues/132), but currently the speed difference is not negligible enough. As of Rust 1.19.0, there is *some* overhead even for a simple "hello world" program which does not panic or cause a compiler error:

```
| RUST_BACKTRACE      | time (seconds) |
|---------------------|----------------|
| compile and execute |           2.48 |
| execute             |           2.02 |
| disabled            |           1.64 |
```

- **compile and execute** - `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run`
- **execute** - `CARGO_TARGET_X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_RUNNER='env RUST_BACKTRACE=1' cargo run`
- **disabled** - `cargo run`

The overhead has not been consistent over time; In 1.14.0, simply having it enabled [caused 10-20 seconds of delay on certain platforms](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37477)! Before then, I never *noticed* any slowness.

---

Editorially, it does not appear that the performance of compiled Rust code when `RUST_BACKTRACE` is enabled is currently a prime concern of the Rust team. There are many other interesting things to evaluate, besides! For these reasons, I would be loathe to have it on all the time. Of course, if the compiler itself turned on the setting by default, then I would expect it to be much more attention-worthy!

Comment: Are your results measured on Rust Playground itself? (I don't see how a hello world program would take so long otherwise). If so, wouldn't times wildly fluctuate depending on how busy the server is at the moment?

Comment: @interjay check out [the issue (expanding the details link)](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/issues/132#issuecomment-318860259) to see the test methodology. Docker is involved, yes, but there's no other load on my local system.

Comment: I've done some testing, and `RUST_BACKTRACE` appears to slow both rustc (even with no errors) and cargo (even when recompile is not needed). However, a hello world program should take near 0 time to run with or without this setting.

Comment: @interjay interesting — I realized I pasted the wrong execution string for the *execute* row. The fixed version still doesn't seem like it should be triggering either of the cases you identify though. I'm not sure what else it would be...

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a happy few hours chasing down a performance issue. I found it was caused by backtrace=1. On my system it caused a 20 x slowdown! I am on Windows.